# Is Google spreadsheets =ImportHtml() done locally or on a Google server?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

Immediate problem:

```
=ImportHtml("http://127.0.0.1/~themis/transactions.html";"table";1)
```

is placed into a cell.  The page exists; I can open it in Chrome.
My guess is that it's done remotely as the error is "the data
could not be retrieved".

My original problem:
I want  [this](http://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view&pid=1) original page from google finance.  However,
that table is created by javascript; using that original 
URL fails because the table doesn't exist and ImportHtml doesn't execute 
javascript.  So I open the page with Chrome's developer tools, copy the root 
DOM as HTML, and write it to the above transactions.html file.  Hacky, but 
I don't need live data.

Any ideas on a solution to either the immediate or original problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, all the Google spreadsheet operations are done remotely.

It does appear that you could use the [ImportXML spreadsheet function](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507) along with the [GoogleFinance Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Transactions) to get your transaction information into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try the GoogleFinance Data API.

Comment: Is this still the case on the new version of Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Since several years ago, Google Sheets has the [GOOGLEFINANCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en), so IMPORTHTML and "hacky" workarounds to import Google Finance data into Google spreadsheet might no longer required.

Regarding IMPORTHTML being done locally or on the server, one part is done on the server, the one that connects to the resource host, the on the client side is done the "recalculation", distributing the data across the cells, etc.

Related

- [Debugging ImportHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51383052/1595451)

Reference

- [Add financial data to a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308730?hl=en)