# How to import Javascript tables into Google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-sheets

I want to import table in "https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/" to my Google sheets. I tried to use IMPORTDATA, IMPORTHTML but it didn't work. I understand that the tables are of Javascript. I don't know about Java or code and I am really trying to learn. Kindly help me with the procedure for importing data.

The formulas that i used are`IMPORTDATA("https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/")` 
which resulted in some java type output and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEfPr.jpg)

other is`IMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/","table",1)` 
which give error "imported content is empty".

Comment: Show formulas you tried, etc.

Comment: The formulas that i used areIMPORTDATA("https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/") which resulted in some java type output and

other isIMPORTHTML("https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/","table",1) which give error "imported content is empty".

Comment: Those should be a part of your question and not a comment.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your suggestion. I edited as you told. Kindly help me.

Comment: What does the &quot;java type output&quot; look like? A screenshot of the cell would be a great addition to your question. Also, did you try other table indices?

Comment: @tehhowch I tried uploading it's showing I don't have 10 reputation points to post images. Instead I posted link. I tried from 0 to 10 number in IMPORTHTML function after "table" but all comes same "imported content is empty".

Answer (score 3):

The reason [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) fails to import the table is because that "table" is dynamically supplied by the website. If you view the page source for https://www.screener.in/screens/1/The-Bull-Cartel/, you'll note that there are no `table` or `list` elements present. Those elements are required for the `IMPORTHTML` function to work.

Similarly, [`IMPORTDATA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) requires you point it at a comma or tab-separated file.

#### Summary: the website you want to scrape does not support scraping in the manner needed by Google Sheet's 'import__' formulas.

You'll have to communicate with the website owners to find out how you can legally acquire the data they display.

Comment: Thank you for your time and for your reply. Actually i can able to copy the data and paste it in Google sheets. Then the link addresses inside the table are also copied. But I want to do it automatically. Is there no other way? Do UrlFetchApp in Google appscript will not work?

Comment: Is there any way I can use solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020041/importing-javascript-table-into-google-docs-spreadsheet to solve my problem?I can't able to understand how I convert my url to JSON type of url as show in solution in that link (var url =)

Comment: That solution was offered because the website in question for that answer offered a JSON file of data. The website you want to get data from might. You will have to **contact your desired website** in order to find out how they are willing to allow you programmatic access. They may say "No."

Comment: First of all sorry if you feel that I am stubborn. I am really trying hard to get a solution. I don&#39;t think they will reply even if I contact. But that website is not secretive. They even provide csv file in some cases like https://www.screener.in/company/BPCL/. Kindly see if information in https://github.com/Mittal-Analytics/Screener.in/blob/master/README.md is anyway useful for my problem. As I am completely unaware of programming I can&#39;t able to understand anything in that link.

Answer (score -3):

https://blog.coupler.io/googlefinance-function-advanced-tutorial/#How_to_get_dividend_data_and_options_from_stocks_using_GOOGLEFINANCE_function

inspired this:
=importxml(concatenate("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/",concatenate(index(split(C34, ":"), 0, 2),":",index(split(C34, ":"), 0, 1))),"/html/body/c-wiz/div/div[3]/main/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]")

Where c34 is a reference to a goolgefinance formated symbol e.g. nasdaq:msft

The above pulls the annual div%