# Web Scraping by google sheet

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to scrape data from link below:
http://fipiran.ir/Symbol/HistoryPrice?symbolpara=%DA%86%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%BE%D8%A7

and Also I want 365 rows of the table.
I tried:

```
=importhtml("http://fipiran.ir/Symbol/HistoryPrice?symbolpara=%DA%86%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%BE%D8%A7","table",0)
```

and

```
=importxml("http://fipiran.ir/Symbol/HistoryPrice?symbolpara=%DA%86%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%BE%D8%A7","//*[@id='gbox_grid']
")
```

But nothing comes out.

Comment: It's a second table on this website. But I can't import it either. It may be protected. Try using Importfromweb scrapping tool (Google Sheets AddOn). It helped me a few times: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/importfromweb_easy_web_scraping/278587576794

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `IMPORTHTML` on the page because this page is loaded dynamically via JavaScript ([see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149751/how-to-import-javascript-tables-into-google-spreadsheet)).

What you can do, though, is use the API call it does ([example](http://fipiran.ir/Symbol/HistoryPricePaging?symbolpara=%DA%86%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%BE%D8%A7&_search=false&nd=1609942590674&rows=180&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc)) and get the data that way. I’m not sure if this is allowed intentionally or not, and you should check with the owners of the page.

You can add a function that does that in Google Apps Script:

```js
function IMPORTJSON(url, columns) {
 if (!Array.isArray(columns)) return []
 columns = columns.flat()
 
 const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
 return JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data.map(
   obj => columns.map(key => obj[key])
 )
}
```

And to use it:

```
=IMPORTJSON("http://example.com/xxx", ["propertyCol1", "propertyCol2", "etc"])
```

Notice that this example ignores pagination and uses the data only from the first page.