# Debugging ImportHTML

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-finance

I'm trying to create a dividend tracker in Google Sheets using the ImportHTML function.

This URL: https://www.google.com/finance?q=VZ works fine in the browser, but  gets an error in ImportHTML claiming that it cannot fetch the URL (that just worked.)

This is the way I'm using the function:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=VZ","table",3)
```

I got the number 3 from various online resources, and I'm able to import other kinds of URLs.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their robots.txt file includes:

```
Disallow: /finance?*q=*
```

In other words, you are not doing anything wrong.